# javascript inline callback function to separate function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is this code working:

```
function onCordovaReady() { 
    navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(function (locale) {
        jQuery.i18n.properties({
            name:'message', 
            path:'lang/', 
            mode:'map',
            language:locale.value,
            callback: function(){
                alert(locale.value);
                alert(jQuery.i18n.prop('msg_hello'));
                alert(jQuery.i18n.prop('msg_complex', 'John'));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And this one not:

```
function onCordovaReady() { 
    navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(function (locale) {
        jQuery.i18n.properties({
            name:'message', 
            path:'lang/', 
            mode:'map',
            language:locale.value,
            callback: onLanguageReady(locale)
        });
    });
}

function onLanguageReady(locale) {
     alert(locale.value);
     alert(jQuery.i18n.prop('msg_hello'));
     alert(jQuery.i18n.prop('msg_complex', 'John'));    
}
```

I want to make the callback in a different function so my code will look cleaner, but couldn't get it to work. The first alert will work (it will display nl_NL), but the second and third alert will output [msg_hello] and [msg_complex].

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
// beginning of code omitted
callback: function(locale) {
    onLanguageReady(locale)
}
```

Comment: This does not work completely, it works if i remove the line:
alert(locale.value);
When i leave the line in there the javascript code just freezes.

Comment: Where is the `locale` variable defined?

Comment: I guess it is defined in navigator.globalization.getLocaleName this is from the cordova/phonegap plugin. [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#globalization.getLocaleName)

Answer (score 2):

it is because you are assigning `undefined` to the `callback` property.

You are calling `onLanguageReady` and assigns that value to the callback method.

The solution is to use another function as callback function which will call the `onLanguageReady` function as given by @romainberger

Answer (score 0):

```
function onCordovaReady() { 
    navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(function (locale) {
        jQuery.i18n.properties({
            name:'message', 
            path:'lang/', 
            mode:'map',
            language:locale.value,
            callback: onLanguageReady
        });
    });
}

function onLanguageReady(locale) {
     alert(locale.value);
     alert(jQuery.i18n.prop('msg_hello'));
     alert(jQuery.i18n.prop('msg_complex', 'John'));    
}
```

will work if the function calls back with locale.

the callback is expecting a function pointer that it can call once the processing is done when you say `onLanguageReady(locale)` you are actually executing the function and thus assigning the result of the function as the call back in this case the return is nothing thus `undefined`

Comment: this works if i remove the alert(locale.value); line, 

but i also need locale.value